# Shell script refer to another directory when building Dockerfile

Tags: shell-script, docker

I am using MacOS.

My project directory structure is like this:

```
myapp/
  app.js
  Dockerfile
  subapp/
      Dockerfile
  script/
     - myshell.sh
```

In `myshell.sh` , I write shell script to build the Dockerfile located under `subapp/` directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
docker build -t myreg/my-sub-app:1.0 -f ../subapp/Dockerfile .
```

In my terminal, under project root `myapp/` I run my shell script:`sh script/myshell.sh`

I get docker error:

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount330496679/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

I see it is a context related issue. could someone please elaborate for me what is the cause of the error & what is the right way in shell script to refer to another directory like this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paths are relative to the current directory (`myapps` in your case), not the directory containing the script:

```
docker build -t myreg/my-sub-app:1.0 -f subapp/Dockerfile .
```